# Are two google projects needed to deploy a google servlet and google endpoint to appengine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

When I use google endpoints and also want to use a servlet how can I deploy both of them to my appengine? Or do I need to set up a project for each of them?

**Edit**
Right now I just can deploy one and if I want to upload another one the new one is just deployed.

Or can I just implement a second class that extends HttpServlet besides MyEndpoint class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Endpoints are a feature of App Engine and your application can have both Endpoints and other servlets. Endpoints are mapped to paths under /_ah/ which is reserved for GAE stuff. You can map your servlets to other paths.

Regarding deployment, a GAE project can contain one application, but you can split it into multiple modules which will be mapped to different subdomains, and each module can be deployed individually.